# I have an html I want to send values of selected options as url parameteres. With this javascript:

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html:

```
<select name="garden" multiple="multiple" id="garden">
  <option value="1">Flowers</option>
  <option value="2">Shrubs</option>
  <option value="6">Trees</option>
  <option value="3">Bushes</option>
  <option value="4">Grass</option>
  <option value="5">Dirt</option>
</select>
<select name="po" multiple="multiple" id="po">
  <option value="1">po1</option>
  <option value="2">po2</option>
  <option value="6">po3</option>
  <option value="3">po4</option>
  <option value="4">po5</option>
  <option value="5">po6</option>
</select>
<div></div>
```

I want to send values of selected options as url parameteres. With this javascript:

```
$("select").change(function () { 
    var str = "";
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
        var option = $(this);
        str += '&' + option.attr('name') + "="+ option.attr('value');   
    });
    $("div").text(str);
});
```

When the other select box changes, str is replaced with another:

How can I send values to url without replacing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Send how exactly? With ajax, a redirect or what ?

Comment: Identical questin [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581661/multiple-select-box-and-send-values-as-url-parameteres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581661/multiple-select-box-and-send-values-as-url-parameteres)

Comment: a form tag will submit a url like this automatically, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your jquery code like below.

```
$("select").change(function () { 
     var str = "";
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {        
       str += "&"+$(this).parent().attr('name')+"="+ $(this).attr('value');             
       });
      $("div").text(str);
    })
    .trigger('change');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eZKUU/55/)

Comment: i am taking the id inside the loop like this `$(this).parent().attr('name')`